# Using the join pandas function in python error

Tags: python, pandas, join

I'm following along a tutorial here on Time Series Analysis - but they do all of the loading in and cleaning of the dataframe work for you.

In attempt to learn and get better at that part myself, I am trying to use the join function to then subsequently calculate the percent change and correlation of the two columns. The data is SPX.csv and ^TNX.csv - the SP500 index fund and bonds, respectively.

```
# Import pandas and plotting modules
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


stocks = pd.read_csv('data/SPX.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')
bonds = pd.read_csv('data/^TNX.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')

''' #not sure if its something to do with the index_col?
stocks = pd.read_csv('data/SPX.csv')
######
bonds = pd.read_csv('data/^TNX.csv')

'''

stocks.index = pd.to_datetime(stocks.index)
bonds.index = pd.to_datetime(bonds.index)

# Convert the stock index and bond index into sets
set_stock_dates = set(stocks.index)
set_bond_dates = set(bonds.index)

# Take the difference between the sets and print
print(set_stock_dates - set_bond_dates)


stocks_and_bonds = stocks.join(bonds, how='inner')
```

The idea is to then be able to do the following -

```
# Compute percent change using pct_change()
returns = stocks_and_bonds.pct_change()

# Compute correlation using corr()
correlation = returns['SP500'].corr(returns['US10Y'])
print("Corelation of stocks and interest rates: ", correlation)

# Make scatter plot
plt.scatter(returns['SP500'], returns['US10Y'])
plt.show()
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your error message? It would help identify the problem you are having. If you are getting something like`ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Date'], dtype='object')`, then I think the problem is that the column names of your data frames are the same. To correct this, you can use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to change a column name.

it would look like this for you

```
Bonds.rename(columns={"Date": "Date_bonds")
```

Comment: Sorry - yes that is the error. Your advice helped, thank you!
    ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Adj Close'], dtype='object')

Comment: If my post answered your question, could you please select it as the answer? [This page] (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) explains how accepting an answer works. If not, what else is wrong?